# Insert Between Grandchildren Nodes with LXML in Python

Tags: xml, parsing, python-3.x, insert, lxml

I am trying to update an iTunes podcast XML and need to put information above the first ***item*** tag. I have tried using minidom and lxml.etree, but cannot seem to drill down far enough to begin inserting where I need to. Here is the XML and the code I have tried most recently, which errors out because lxml turns the child nodes into a list.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<rss xmlns:itunes="http://www.itunes.com/dtds/podcast-1.0.dtd" version="2.0">
   <channel>
    <title>Title</title>
    <link>weblink</link>
    <language>en-us</language>
    <copyright>Copyright</copyright>
    <itunes:subtitle>Subtitle</itunes:subtitle>
    <itunes:author>Author</itunes:author>
    <itunes:summary>Summary</itunes:summary>
    <description>Description</description>
    <itunes:owner>
        <itunes:name>Owner Name</itunes:name>
        <itunes:email>Owner email</itunes:email>
    </itunes:owner>
    <itunes:image image.jpg"/>
    <itunes:category text="MISC">
        <itunes:category text="MISC"/>
        </itunes:category> 
    <itunes:block>no</itunes:block>
    <itunes:explicit>no</itunes:explicit>

    <item>
        <title>First Entry</title>
        <itunes:author>Author</itunes:author>
        <itunes:subtitle>Just Another Entry</itunes:subtitle>
        <itunes:summary>Podcast Summary.</itunes:summary>
        <enclosure url="url_to_mp3" length="48412967" type="audio/mpeg"/>
        <guid>url_to_mp3</guid>
        <pubDate>Sun, 12 Oct 2014 12:00:00 -0500</pubDate>
        <itunes:duration>00:50:26</itunes:duration>
        <itunes:block>no</itunes:block>
        <itunes:explicit>no</itunes:explicit>
    </item>
```

My current code:

```
from lxml import etree

tree = etree.parse(file)
root = tree.getroot()
child = root.getchildren()
child.insert(13, etree.Element('item'))
child[13].insert(0, etree.SubElement(child[13], 'title'))
```

Thank you for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer that I came up with.

```
from lxml import etree
parser = etree.XMLParser(remove_blank_text=True)
tree = etree.parse('file', parser)
root = tree.getroot()
child = root.find('channel')
new_item = etree.Element('item')
new_title = etree.SubElement(new_item, 'title')
new_title.text = "Test Title"
child.insert(13, new_item)
tree.write('file', pretty_print=True, xml_declaration=True, encoding='UTF-8')
```